# CAS provides non deterministic username attribute for OIDC service when non default username attribut is used for OAUTH service

Tags: cas

I was wondering if I'm miss-understanding the expected behavior of `usernameAttributeProvider` or if it's a bug (and if there is an alternate solution).
I have the following service:

```json
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService",
  ...
  "usernameAttributeProvider": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.PrincipalAttributeRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider",
    "usernameAttribute": "uidNumber",
    "canonicalizationMode": "NONE"
  },
  ...
}
```

The goal is to provide to this service another identifier (`uidNumber`) than the one used for other services (default identifier for other services is `uid`).
N.B.: both (`uid` and `uidNumber`) come from LDAP.

This works well (I can connect to the service), but I detected an unexpected behavior.
When a user connects to the above-mentioned service, in CAS logs, the `WHO:` is the `uid` for every `ACTION` except for `SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATED` for which it is the `uidNumber`.
After connecting to the above-mentioned service (and **only after connecting to this specific service**), if the user accesses an `OidcRegisteredService` service, the `sub` in the OIDC response is the `uidNumber` whereas it is expecting to receive the `uid` (which makes it fail to authenticate the user). The `OidcRegisteredService` service configuration doesn't provide any specific config for the usernameAttribute:

```json
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.OidcRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "id": ...,
  "clientId": "...",
  "clientSecret": "...",
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "scopes": ["java.util.HashSet", ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"]]
}
```

That means that depending on whether the user connected to the first described `OAuthRegisteredService` or not, he can connect to the `OidcRegisteredService` service or not.
Note that it doesn't affect other `RegexRegisteredService` services or a `SamlRegisteredService` that specifies its own `usernameAttributeProvider`.

I also tried forcing the `usernameAttributeProvider`: it doesn't change what is received in the `sub` (still `uid` or `uidNumber` depending on whether the user connected to the `OAuthRegisteredService` before or not):

```json
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.OidcRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "id": ...,
  "clientId": "...",
  "clientSecret": "...",
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "scopes": ["java.util.HashSet", ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"]],
  "usernameAttributeProvider": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.PrincipalAttributeRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider",
    "usernameAttribute": "uid"
  }
}
```

N.B.: CAS version is 5.2.7

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

You are not. Most likely, this is a bug that should be fixed, or you can patch server yourself since your CAS version has been EOL for many years.

Modify [this line](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/5.2.x/support/cas-server-support-oidc/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/oidc/token/OidcIdTokenGeneratorService.java#L128) in your CAS overlay and use the `service` parameter to re-calculate the username/subject.

Comment: Thanks @misagh-moayyed.
If I understand well, it was a bug that was still existing in current version and I should inspire from https://github.com/apereo/cas/commit/079f9b977098e4ebdabfaa2d1d74d2e92d272334#diff-a525be753615ee1c1b5f84f8b35ac6d79203f8a7a514abf7b628eecdd747b1e9R117 to backport the fix.
But the code has diverged from my version and I also fail to see how storing the subject in a variable that is logged (but not set as claim subject) could fix anything.
Or maybe the fix is elsewhere in your commit?